# Replace GET variables with slashes .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use .htaccess to make my url's "prettier".

Changing **domain.com/page/val1**

To **domain.com/page.php?var1=val1**

If possible, I would like it to work with 2 variables as well:

Changing **domain.com/page/val1/val2**

To **domain.com/page.php?var1=val1&var2=val2**

This is my current .htaccess file that works to remove the .php extension:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I've found other topics with solutions similar to adding something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2?var1=$3&var2=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I've tried many ways to modify it and it never seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?var1=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work when I changed the placement of some variables. **But** for some reason, links to stylesheets and images aren't working in my page anymore.

Comment: I seem to have fixed the src issue by using the full url of the image/stylesheet. Not preferable, but it works.

Comment: For pretty URLs to work it is always better to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.