# How to remove .php and replace ? with / in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How do I remove `.php` and replace `?` with `/` at the same time.

I have

```
http://localhost/testingproject/testing.php?mode=getdata
```

I want it to be called from the browser like this:

```
http://localhost/testingproject/testing/getdata
```

In replacing `?` data, I want it to be compatible with dir.

Like in dir, I have:

```
testing.php
user.php
dashboard.php
```

So, if the user calls `http://localhost/testingproject/user`, alone, there is no need to parse `?` to `/` as `user` is a valid PHP file: `user.php`.

But if user the calls `http://localhost/testingproject/user/abc`, then `user.php` page should get `$_GET['mode']` value `abc`.

I've searched but still cannot find compatible htaccess code.

Comment: It might be a better idea to do the routing from inside the main file (index.php usually), and use .htaccess to only to send all requests to that main file (instead of the 404 page, what it does by default).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess help?

Comment: Yes, for your use-case, a PHP router sounds like the best option. You can go [simple](https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/) or more [complex](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute)

Comment: for now, i can remove .php but cannot get method
so, i can now call test?mode=abc instead of test.php?mode=abc which i need to be test/abc
so currently, my main problem is getting ?mode= as /

Comment: Where are you placing your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: xampp/htdocs/testproject/backend/
dir of backend.
.htaccess
test.php
user.php
....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one that works.
Now, i can call http://localhost/testproject/backend/user/abc instead of http://localhost/testproject/backend.php?mode=abc
In [Replace GET variables with slashes .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396872/replace-get-variables-with-slashes-htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?mode=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hello :) you could try this [link](https://www.buzzphp.com/posts/replace-query-string-in-url-using-htaccess)